# I am making a hangman game, i got the logic down but its not working,when i inspect it it says undefined touppercase

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

AS you can see im making a simple hangman game with only html and javascript...ive got the logic down but it doesnt seem to work overall.I inspected the element to see whats wrong it says undefined toUppercase.

Im a newbie programmer so do give me some pointer on how to fix this also pointer me in anything else that it wrong

```js
var keywords=["Apple","Banana","Variety"];
var score=0, fails=0, actualword="", guessword;
    
function startGame()
    {
        
        var num = Math.floor(keywords);
        actualword = keywords[num];
        actualword = actualword.toUpperCase();
        
        for ( i = 0; i < actualword.length; i++)
    {
        guessword += "*";
    }
        document.getElementById("hangman").value = guessword;
        document.getElementById("msg").value = "A word has already been selected, click button below to play game.";
        document.getElementById("score").value = score;
        document.getElementById("fails").value = fails;
    }
    function find(x)
    {
        var found = false;
        for ( i =0; i < actualword.length; i++)
            {
                if(actualword.charAt(i) == x)
                    {
                        guessword = setCharAt(guessword, i, x);
                        found=true;
                    }
            }
        if(found)
            {
                if( guessword == actualword)
                    {
                        alert("Well done!");
                        score++;
                        document.getElementById("msg").value = "Click 'Start' button to select the next keyword";
                        
                    }
            }
        document.getElementById("hangman").value = guessword;
        document.getElementById("score").value =  score;
        document.getElementById("fails").value = fails;
    }
    
    function setCharAt(str,index,chr)
    {
        return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HangMan Game - Javascript</title>
<script>
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<form name="f">

<table bgcolor="#C0C0C0" border="1">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td colspan="4" align="right">
   Score : <input type="text" name="score" value="0" size="2">
   <br>
   Fails (6): <input type="text" name="fails" value="0"size="2">  
  </td>
  <td colspan="7" align="CENTER">
   <input type="text" name="hangman" value="    --- Hangman ---" size="25"> 
    <br>
   <input type="text" name="msg" value="Click GO to get a word." size="25">  
  </td>
  <td colspan="2" align="center">
   <input type="button" onclick="startGame()" value=" START ">   
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" A " onclick="find('A');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" B " onclick="find('B');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" C " onclick="find('C');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" D " onclick="find('D');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" E " onclick="find('E');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" F " onclick="find('F');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" G " onclick="find('G');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" H " onclick="find('H');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" I   " onclick="find('I');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" J  " onclick="find('J');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" K " onclick="find('K');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" L  " onclick="find('L');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" M " onclick="find('M');"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" N " onclick="find('N');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" O " onclick="find('O');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" P " onclick="find('P');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" Q " onclick="find('Q');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" R " onclick="find('R');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" S " onclick="find('S');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" T " onclick="find('T');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" U " onclick="find('U');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" V " onclick="find('V');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" W " onclick="find('W');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" X  " onclick="find('X');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" Y " onclick="find('Y');"></td>
  <td><input type="BUTTON" value=" Z  " onclick="find('Z');"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a lot of problems in the code, so I suggest you start at the beginning and use `console.log` to see what values you are working with and work out why they are giving an error. For example, `console.log(num)` after `var num = Math.floor(keywords);` will immediately show you there's a problem on the very first line that executes. Work though it line by line and you will find the errors you need to work on!

Comment: ok thks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the below 3 lines of code

```
var num = Math.floor(keywords);
actualword = keywords[num];
actualword = actualword.toUpperCase();
```

Here actualword is undefined that's why it's giving error.
Now actualword is undefined because keywords[nums] is not returning proper element, that's because Math.floor(keywords) return NaN

So the problem is at line Math.floor(keywords).

Comment: ah i see thks for help